# Push is not a function when trying to push element in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've got the following piece of code:

```
const timeframes = {};
let calendars = this.state.calendars;
for(let i = 0; i < this.state.rows; i++) {
  if(timeframes[calendars[i][0]]) {
    timeframes[calendars[i][0]].push(calendars[i][0]); //THROWS ERROR
  } else {
    timeframes[calendars[i][0]] = calendars[i][1];
  }
}
```

I'm simply trying to build some sort of JSON style data.
For example calendar might look like this:

```
[["Lunes", "mañana"], ["Lunes", "tarde"], ["Martes", "mañana"], ["Jueves", "mañana"]]
```

So what I'm trying to do in that code is to set the values "mañana" and "tarde" to the key "Lunes". The other values are not the problem in this example since they don't fall in that if condition which throws the error.

I'm unable to push it the way I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the object which doesn't have a `push` method?  Perhaps `console.log(timeframes[calendars[i][0]]);` ?

Comment: You never create any array to push to

Comment: I think what you wanted to do is `else { timeframes[calendars[i][0]] = [calendars[i][1]] }`

Comment: Are you resolve this question?